# What are practical uses for the Custom fields within an alert in Microsoft SCOM?

Tags: scom

How are people in the real world using custom fields in Microsoft System Operations Manager 2007? Are they useful? How do you interact with them?

So far, I've only found [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/steverac/archive/2010/08/17/updating-custom-alert-fields-using-subscriptions-and-powershell.aspx) but I'm looking for more samples to fully appreciate the value (or lack of) for these fields.

Answer (score 0):

These can be filled using powershell/orchestrator/vbscript/... This is used e.g. for adding SLA or environment information to an alert or to help the interaction with ticketing systems.